# How to I reference the value of a selected item in dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html.actionlink

Pls look at following code

```
                <select name="VideoType" id="VideoType" style="width:60px">
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="Movie">Movie</option>
                <option value="Show">Show</option>
            </select>

<ul id="categories">
    @foreach (var genre in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(genre.Title, 
            "Browse", "Store",
              new { Genre = genre.Title, VideoType =   }, null)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

As U can see in the actionlink, how do i ref the selected value of dropdownlist? For eg: Movie.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Darin said, you do it in javascript.

Add an id attribute to your anchor tag so that we can refer using that.

```
@Html.ActionLink(genre.Title, 
            "Browse", "Store",
              new { Genre = genre.Title, VideoType =   }, new { @id="link1"})
```

Then using javascript, change the link,

```
$(function(){

  $("#VideoType").change(function(){
      $("#link1").attr("href")="Store/"+$("#VideoType").val();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because the ActionLink is generated on the server, whereas the selected value of the dropdown might change on the client. You will have to use javascript and subscribe to the `onchange` event of the dropdown and then modify the link of the anchor to include the selected value.